# Why is this JSON query not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am so confused at the moment, as to why this will not work.

```
<div id="result" style="color:red"></div>
```

and

```
var getJSON = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function() {
  var status = xhr.status;
  if (status == 200) {
    resolve(xhr.response);
  } else {
    reject(status);
  }
};
xhr.send();
  });
};

getJSON('https://www.eobot.com/api.aspx?coin=DOGE&json=true').then(function(data) {
alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.DOGE); //you can comment this, i used it to debug

result.innerText = data.DOGE; //display the result in an HTML element
}, function(status) { //error detection....
  alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```

It's exactly the same as: http://jsfiddle.net/RamiSarieddine/HE2nY/1/ but yet that works..

Edit: For the sake of clarity, the script is supposed to take the content at the url (within the DOGE element) and display it within

```
<div id="result" style="color:red"></div>
```

Comment: What does "not working? mean?

Comment: @AndyRay It does not output anything. Edit: e.g. <div id="result" style="color:red"></div> remains empty. It should put the contents of the url element DOGE into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it and i get below error, Which means when you try to get the json from `https://www.eobot.com/api.aspx?coin=DOGE&json=true` , its blocked from receiving the data due to cross browser rules.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
```

How to fix it ,

You must own `https://www.eobot.com` and run this script on `www.eobot.com` , Else you cant get the json due to cross domain policy.Ask the owner to whitelist your domain in his allow-origin header.